# _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) when cash view in django

Tags: django

Error in first line of:

```
@cache_page(3600)
def get_big_items_html():
    ....
    return 'some html string'
```

Here is my settings.py

```
CACHES = {
   'default': {
      'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
      'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Functional based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view) need to take a `request` argument, so here is fix:

```
@cache_page(3600)
def get_big_items_html(request):
    ....
    return HttpResponse('some html string')
```

Comment: so it helps, but i get another error: 'SafeText' object has no attribute 'streaming'. I have categories on my site, must get all categories and template for rendering categories, i want save in cash string which is merge result of categories with its template.

Comment: View need to return HttpResponse object, so just change to `return HttpResponse('your html')`